# Does everything come down to builtin objects in Python?

Tags: python, built-in, cpython

There are functions such as `print` that are embedded in CPython and there are other functions such as `os.makedirs` that are written in external .py files (i.e. in `os.py`).

As far as I know, `print()` would call some C code that is already written inside CPython and that C code would be compiled to bytecode to be understood by the computer.

What happens in the case of `os.makedirs`? That is not embedded in CPython so CPython doesn't know anything about `os.makedirs`.

Or is `makedirs` making use of some objects that can be traced back to built-in objects that CPython knows about?

For example, `os.py` imports `abc.py` which imports `_weakrefset.py` which eventually imports the builtin `_weakref` object? So, `os.py` can be traced to the builtin `_weakref` object, for which, CPython has some C code.

Comment: `sys.path` is not a function; it's a list.

Comment: Oop, just changed that to `print`.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, maybe you are confusing the language and its implementation. This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130975/python-vs-cpython

Comment: *C code would be compiled to bytecode* - no, C is not compiled to byte code, it is Python code which is compiled to byte code.  C is compiled to a form close to machine code, which is a lower level than byte code.  `print` is a builtin function so is logically part of the `builtins` module, `os.makedirs` is part of the `os` module and it could be written in C (or any other language in theory).  How and where they are implemented is not defined by the language.  The point is that these implementation details should not be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

*Does everything come down to builtin objects in Python?*  It depends what you mean by the question, but guessing that you are talking about code flow, then the answer is no.

Take the C implementation of python as our benchmark - remember that there are versions of Python written in Java, C#, and even Python.  Modules can be written in C or C++ since there is an API for that.

Take creating a directory (`mkdir`).  At some point that will require a kernel call which depends on the operating system.  There will, for example, be a Windows and a UNIX or Posix lower-level interface to make the kernel call, and it will almost certainly be written in C.  This is because most modern operating systems have C kernel APIs, not Python ones.

See, for example, `Modules/posixmodule.c` in the Python source, which is where the OS kernel interface `mkdir` is called.  The C interface for creating a directory only has need of a text string (*not* a python `str` object), a C octal integer for permissions, and a variable to store its result.  These have to be converted between C and Python, but there can be other types used internally by the module which are pure C and have no need to be converted back to python.

Just because a module is written in C does not mean it is a builtin (part of the `builtin` module).  You can write your own C module and call it from python - the python user does not need to be aware what language it is written in, that is usually invisible.