# Does graph.nodes() maintain some ordering?

Tags: python, networkx

With networkx2 does the `.nodes()` method guarantee some kind of consistent node ordering, or can we expect the ordering to change between multiple calls on the same graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Up to Python 3.6**

The nodes are kept in a `dictionary`, and `nodes()` return a list of the `dictionary` keys. The order will be constant as long as you don't change anything in the graph nodes. Adding/removing nodes or edges might effect the order.

**From Python 3.6:**

In some Python implementations, like [CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130986/5168011), `dictionary` maintain the insertion order, which mean you can expect the print order, however not all of them

**From Python 3.7:**

Ordered `dictionary` is now language standard.

From the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-0.37/)

```
def nodes(self): 
    """Return a copy of the graph nodes in a list.""" 
    return self.adj.keys()
```

[networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.0/install.html) support Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6, the behavior depends on your version.

Comment: Thanks! but as far as I know, dictionary keys don't guarantee a constant ordering? I may be wrong since I think this changed in python 3.6. Actually, according to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) since 3.7 insertion order is guaranteed. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosG.Oliver Updated my answer.

Comment: Isn't it since 3.7 rather than since 3.6 that the change was made?

Comment: @Joel It wasn't part of the language yet, only part of some implementations, namely CPython which is the common implementation. I will update the answer accordingly.