# How do I view the source code of python modules, such as sys, os, and request modules?

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to understand the backend of the request and sys, and os modules.

I've seen or heard somewhere that python modules are pre-written python codes made to be called later in other scripts with the import command.
I was just curious as to where the module source codes are located so I can read them to better understand some things in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got the right mentality. I've become such a better developer just by taking the time to step through the source code.

You can find all of the Python built-in modules [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Python).

You may notice that some of the built-in modules like [os](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py) and [sys](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/sysmodule.c) are written in C. I’d recommend checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130975/python-vs-cpython) out for a better understanding.

In regards to [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests), it's a third-party library built around [urllib](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/urllib).

Comment: how does python read or interpret files written in other languages.