# Python internal memory management of list

Tags: python

Suppose a list of five element are there . a = [1,2,4,5,6] . and i want to insert element 3 in between , so what will happen if i use insert func of python .

1. A separate memory allocated for element 3 only and its reference is attached to existing
2. A new memory will be allocated to (aproxx 1.3 times of previous memory) whole list and element 3
   attached to it
3. List item

---

---

If option 1 , then why time comp for insert() func is o(n) in python , not o(1)

Answer (score 2):

Solution 2 is correct- it will take more memory.

Python has pointers for everything. So when you create a list, say `foo = [3, 4, 5]`, python attaches a unique id to this list, `foo`, and points each index (position) in the list to the id of the value at the index.

When you do `foo.insert(add_index, val)`, you are *changing* the pointer for all indices after `add_index`. This is why the time complexity is O(n), since n pointer may need to be changed depending on the `add_index` variable.

Memory doesn't scale linearly with what you are adding. The memory used by a list depends on what is being added (str vs float vs int ...) and whether the element is unique (create new pointer vs reference old pointer). In your case, it's correct that the list will approximately take (6/5) times the memory.

Comment: hey , is this for python or cpython ?

Comment: That's a bit of a weird question, since Python is essentially just rules and syntax. The actual implementation of the language is done using cpython by default, although other implementations are there. This may be heplful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130975/python-vs-cpython