# Please explain to me how does Python interpreter executes modules written in C/C++?

Tags: python, c, virtual-machine, interpreter, python-internals

I'm trying to understand how it works. I know that Python interpreter translates python source code to byte code representation for a virtual machine (Python interpreter is a virtual machine) and executes those instructions. Where exactly does a C/C++ code comes in here? Does this virtual machine (Python interpreter) can also compile and execute C/C++ code?

I don't even know exactly what are right questions to ask here, just want a good explanation of how.

My background: I programmed in Python for a long time (mostly analytics/ML) and I have some basic understanding of computer systems, C compilation process, memory and processor. But I am not even close to being an expert on it.

I just want good understanding, not so much practical tips on how to create a Python module in C.

Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17130975/238704

Answer (score 4):

It's all about a predictable entrypoint. The CPython reference interpreter (and other interpreters like PyPy that support C extensions of this sort), told to look for a module of a given name and finding a file matching the naming conventions for extension modules in one of the `sys.path` directories (e.g. for the `spam` module built for CPython 3.10 on x86-64 Linux, it would look for `spam.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`):

1. Uses the OS standard method for loading a dynamic library (aka shared object), e.g. `LoadLibrary` on Windows, `dlopen` on POSIX systems
2. Loads the entrypoint (using `GetProcAddress` on Windows, `dlsym` on POSIX) in it matching [the specified naming convention](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function), e.g. for the module named `spam`, it looks for a function named `PyInit_spam` following C name-mangling rules
3. Invokes that function, which is then *wholly* responsible for all other setup (calling `PyModule_Create`, performing any modifications to said module object, and returning it). The various APIs it invokes are what publish information for use by the user.

Answer (score 3):

[CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython), the "standard" Python interpreter, is written in C.  It provides an [extension API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) in C, so extensions written in C or C++ can register themselves to be called like normal Python modules.  The Python interpreter cannot compile C or C++; it is the extension writer's responsibility to compile the module.  But Python can *run* arbitrary C and C++ code through the help of that API.